# Changing functions signatures and its parameters: list* to node*

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am creating a program that inverts the non-vowel sequences of a word represented by a list that is singly linked, without head and without sentinel. In other words, each node in the list has a letter field. My program has to invert the non-vowel sequences (spaces, consonants, dots and commas) from this list without modifying the original list.

The algorithm itself is ready and working. My problem lies in **how to transform `LIST*` functions into `NODE*` type functions.** For example, `LIST* toCloneList(LIST* l)` must be `NODE* toCloneList(NODE* p)` and `void decode(LIST* answer)`must be `NODE* decode(NODE* answer)`.

```
LIST* toCloneList(LIST* l){
  LIST* answer = malloc(sizeof(LIST));

  NODE *current = l->first;
  NODE *previous = NULL; 

  while(current){ 
    NODE *newnd = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newnd->letter = current->letter;
    newnd->next = NULL;

    if (previous == NULL){ 
        answer->first = newnd;
    }
    else { 
        previous->next = current;
    }

    previous = newnd;
    current = current->next;
  }

  return answer;
}

void invert(LIST* answer){

    NODE* actual = answer->first;
    answer->first = NULL;

    while (actual != NULL){ 
        NODE* current = actual; 
        actual = actual->next; 


        current->next = answer->first; 
        answer->first = current; 
    }
}

void decode(LIST* answer) {
    NODE* fNv = NULL; //first non-vowel found
    NODE* lNv = NULL;  //last non-vowel found

    NODE* current = answer->first; 
    NODE* previous = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {

        /* While current points to a non-vowel. */
        if (checkSequence(current)) {
            fNv = current;

            /* Searches the last non-vowel case in the list. */
            while (current->next != NULL && checkSequence(current->next)) {
              current = current->next;
            }

            /* When the next letter is a vowel, then the end of the non-vowel sequence is reached. */
            lNv = current;

            /* If there is a non-vowel sequence, in other words, fNv and lNv do not point to the same element, then the position change must be performed. */
            if (fNv != lNv) {
                /* Calls a recursive function to perform the change of positions without having to create a new list. */

                NODE* k = lNv->next;

                invertNvs(fNv->next, fNv, lNv);

                fNv->next = k;

                if (previous == NULL){
                    answer->first = lNv;
                }
                else {
                    previous->next = lNv;
                }

                current = fNv;
            }
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

The program should work for calls like this:

```
NODE* test = null;
test = decode(p);
```

Full code- https://repl.it/LAuW/0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `LIST` at all, use only `NODE` instead. This makes your code much easier.

But, alternatively, if you really wish it, you can introduce a bunch of "thin wrappers", sort of

```
void decodeList(LIST *l)
{
    if (l != 0)
        decodeNode(l->first);
}
```

BTW. Also in the case of switching to C++ you'll have the opportunity to use inline and overloaded functions, which makes it to look more natural, e.g.:

```
inline void decode(LIST& l) { decode(l.first); }
```

Unfortunately, with plain C you can't use overloading, so you have to use different names for the functions.